# Wifi reconnected, no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

After a wifi outage yesterday, my computer has reconnected to the network but cannot access the internet. Other devices are fine, so I presume it is a software problem.

Exactly what that problem is has stumpped me. I have local access, my printer keeps telling me its connected, but I can't ping Google or anything else.

It is running Ubuntu 20.04, if that helps. The wireless card is intell Wifi 6 AX200.

Edit: I am asking for how to properly reconnect to the internet. I am currently trying the DNS configuration route, but it is not yet working. Changing  the value manualy to 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 is doing nothing.

Edit 2: Entering /etc/resolve.conf gives "No such file directory" If that is of any use to the reader.

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8?  If you can then it looks like a dns configuration issue, if not then it is a routing issue.  Please supply more information regarding the network config, the output of the following will be useful.  `netstat -rnv`.  `ifconfig -a`  `more /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I can ping that address, the output of the code you sent me is "Command 'netstat' not found but can be installed with: sudo apt install net-tools

Comment: Your problem is with the DNS configuration, check out the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`. This post may also help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244860/dns-issues-after-upgrading-to-20-04

Comment: The file for your edit 2 was `/etc/resolv.conf` not `/etc/resolve.conf` to see the contents type `more /etc/resolv.conf`.   When you said that you were setting the DNS configuration  manually to 8.8.8.8 and it didn't work, can you explain what you doing to accomplish this?