# Cannot connect to the wired internet on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dns

I have an issue similar to what is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244860/dns-issues-after-upgrading-to-20-04). I tried all the answers in that posting as well as other similar questions with no luck. I have also zero understanding in networking and really need help with it. The fresh installation worked fine,but then I have probably run the system upgrade and since then the internet access is broken.
One thing I have noticed that when modifying nameserver line in `/etc/resolv.conf`  ,the NetworkManager always resets it to 127.0.0.53.   I tried disabling that service, deleting the resolv.conf but it always returns.I will update the question with any extra info on request.

I have tried also [this](https://www.cyberithub.com/solved-no-internet-connection-after-installation-of-ubuntu-20-04/) solution. But when pinging google.com I am getting:

```
ping: google.com:Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Here is the relevant output from `lspci`:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

And `lshw -c network`:

```
*-network                 
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
    logical name: enp3s0
    version: 15
    serial: 4c:cc:6a:2b:b7:05
    size: 100Mbit/s
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
    resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df104000-df104fff memory:df100000-df103fff
```

I have also tried to boot in secure mode  <s>and from the installation USB</s>  and same problem persists. It can't be a hardware issue as I have Windows in dual boot there which connects to the internet fine.
I updated the above: when loading from installation Flash disk the wired internet does work.

Here is the output of `sudo service systemd-resolved`:

```
systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; ve>
    Active: inactive (dead)
    Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
    ...
```

After I have restarted the service I am getting this:

```
systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-01-21 16:03:30 EET; 9s ago
    Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
                 https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
                 https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
                 https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
    Main PID: 2826 (systemd-resolve)
    Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 19082)
    Memory: 4.7M
    CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
    └─2826 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Starting Network Name Resolution...
Positive Trust Anchors: 
    systemd-resolved[2826]: . IN DS 20326 8 2
    e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d  
    systemd-resolved[2826]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa
    16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18>   systemd-resolved[2826]: Using system hostname 'sasmaster-ubuntu20'.   systemd[1]:

Started Network Name Resolution.
```

Comment: The first line in `resolve.conf` says the file is managed by a service and the second line says, quote: "Do not edit.". Not sure why you would want to play around with the file given the rest of the notes in that file . That said, could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of: (0) `sudo lspci` (1) `sudo lshw -c network`? This will show detailed information about your hardware and network, making it more likely someone can offer a solution 

Comment: Yes,sure.Adding it.

Comment: The hardware appears to have the correct driver and it's showing as being connected. What do you see when you run `resolvectl status`? Are there a bunch of records for `DNSSEC NTA` up near the top? Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo service systemd-resolved status`? 

Comment: I have re-enabled and restarted the service. The internet is back!!! It didn't work the previous time I did it. I will restart and check if the fix persists.

Comment: Looks like you may have some DNS resolution now. Are you still seeing an error?

Comment: Restarted after reenabling the resolve and not the internet indeed work. Weird. I have tried that already during the last 2 hours and had no luck. You have a good karma. Thanks!