# Cannot resolve hostnames on ping after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, network-manager, dns

I have recently upgraded a server running 18.04 to 20.04. The in-place upgrade seemed to go fine and installed without a hiccup, however the end goal is to upgrade to 22.04 and when I went to go run the do-release-upgrade command to step up the upgrade again, it would hang up on:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
```

I get this output after canceling the do-release-upgrade]:

[image: Output after canceling do-release-upgrade]

I followed the steps listed in  [this Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244860/dns-issues-after-upgrading-to-20-04?newreg=77e3dedd93f04f389241cb6e1623287c) and attempted to adapt them for our static setup and made the changes to the referenced files, but I still cannot upgrade or ping via hostnames.

my /etc/network/interfaces file is as follows:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 10.1.0.251
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 10.1.0.0
 broadcast 10.1.0.255
 gateway 10.1.0.1
 dns-nameservers 72.1.48.132 8.8.8.8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DNS issues after upgrading to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244860/dns-issues-after-upgrading-to-20-04)

Comment: Also, I would recommend upgrading to netplan, then remove the legacy `/etc/network/interfaces` and `net-tools`. It will be pretty straightforward to rewrite your static configuration as a netplan definition.

Comment: yeah that link is the exact link I posted as the "this Ask Ubuntu post" and as mentioned it did not help me. 

I will looking into making my static a netplan and remove the deprecated methods. Thank you for that advice. I will let you know how it goes.